# Make a rectangle bounce depending on the wall it touched in PYGAME

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates

Im trying to make a rectangle bounce, without going off limits.
I want my rectangle to bounce depending on the wall it touched.
In this code im trying to bounce the rectangle in a 90º angle, but it isn't working.

---

Im using this to calculate each advance:

```
 rect_x += rectxSpeed
 rect_y += rectySpeed
```

---

When it reachs the limit

```
if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
    rectySpeed=5
    rect_y=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)

if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
    rectxSpeed=5
    rectx_y=rectxSpeed*-(math.pi/2)
```

---

Whole code here:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
rect_x= 50.0
rect_y = 50.0
rectxSpeed=5
rectySpeed=5

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # --- Game logic should go here

    # --- Screen-clearing code goes here

    # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.

    # If you want a background image, replace this clear with blit'ing the
    # background image.
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    string=str(rect_x)
    string2=str(rect_y)
    string3="["+string+"]"+"["+string2+"]"
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
    text = font.render(string3,True,RED)
    screen.blit(text, [0, 0])    
    #Main rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [rect_x, rect_y, 50, 50]) 
    #Second rectangle inside the rectangle 1
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rect_x+10, rect_y+10, 30, 30])  
    rect_x += rectxSpeed
    rect_y+=rectySpeed
    if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
        rectySpeed=5
        rect_y=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)
    if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
        rectxSpeed=5
        rect_x=rectxSpeed*-(math.pi/2)

    # --- Drawing code should go here

    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(20)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

¿How can i adjust the advance?

This code produce this:

[image: This code produce this]

---

By Changing the reach limit code with:

```
if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
    rectySpeed=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)

   if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
    rectxSpeed=rectxSpeed*-(math.pi/2)
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: `rectySpeed=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)` doesn't really make sense.  `rectySpeed` is a scalar velocity, but `-(math.pi/2)` is an angle in radians.  What exactly do you expect to happen when you multiply these together?

Comment: I thought that might change the direction of the rectangle in a 90º degree angle. But clearly it isnt working.

Comment: I think you may be overthinking this. If the x limits are ever reached, you simply just want to change the direction the object is moving, so just multiplying by -1 should achieve what you want, unless I'm missing something. Same for the y limits, multiple the speed (scalar) of the rectangle object by -1.

Comment: Actually. That's the answer I reached when I started this project. But I want the rectangle to bounce depending on the wall It touched. Because if I multiple the speed by -1 it just keep doing the same pattern.

Comment: Do you want it to do different things based on the specific wall that it bounced off of?

Comment: Exactly. But i don't get it to work.

Comment: You need to update your question to explain what you want to occur based on the specific wall that it comes into contact with. I cannot tell from your OP what the intended functionality is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's important to recognize here that the **speed** of the rectangle object here is a scalar value, not it's vector counterpart **velocity**. You are attempting to multiply the `rectySpeed` (a scalar value) by `-(math/pi)/2`, which is a value that will be returned in radians as @0x5453 mentioned. As far as the rectangle bouncing differently depending on the wall that it contacted, you have not specified the differing constraints that you intend to impose. I think you may want to consider **why** you want the rectangle to **always** bounce at a 90° angle. Note that a rectangle that always bounces at a 90° angle would yield some very odd functionality to the player/user.

The angle that the rectangle is approaching the wall measured from the horizontal will be equal to the angle that the rectangle will rebound off the wall measured from the vertical line of the wall to it's new path (in the case of an x-directional bounce).

In terms of an accurate physics engine, you may want to consider just simplifying your mechanics to the following in the case that the rectangle contacts a wall:

```
if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
    rectySpeed=rectySpeed*-1

if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
    rectxSpeed=rectxSpeed*-1
```

The above ensures that the rectangle object simply changes **direction**, therefore the magnitude of the rectangle's **speed** does not change, however the **velocity** indeed does since it is a vector quantity.